# When working with derived entity class what is the EntityValue equivalent of EntityList?

Tags: entity

Suppose I am working with the following derived entity class.

```
derivedClass=FilteredEntityClass[
    EntityClass["ProgrammingLanguage",All],
    EntityFunction[c,StringLength[c["Name"]]==1]
]
```

Now we can get a list of entities from this class as follows.

```
EntityList[derivedClass,True]
```

with its `EntityValue` equivalent

```
EntityValue[derivedClass,"Entities"]
```

But if we want to retain the derivation information in the entities themselves we can use the following syntax.

```
EntityList[derivedClass,False]
```

Now my question is what is the equivalent syntax to use for `EntityValue` to achieve this?

Taking inspiration from

```
RandomEntity["Planet",5]
EntityValue["Planet",{"RandomEntities",5}]
```

Tried the following with no success.

```
EntityValue[derivedClass,{"Entities",False}]
```